# Is there a way to use bootstrap 4 with Sass instead of SCSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I've just installed Bootstrap 4 to my Rails 6 app, and noticed that all files are ***.SCSS***

Is there a way to make Bootstrap use **Sass**?

I use Sass, because it's much easier without all these brackets and semicolons...

Comment: Sure. Just port all the files over to the indented SASS syntax... Should only take you a week or so. Jokes aside the reason why bootstrap and everything else is written in SCSS is interoperability. The indented syntax was not supported on libsass until 2.0 and is not popular.

Comment: For most people having a subset of CSS is a lot more important then "it looks pretty" or "waah semicolons". The indented syntax just adds a lot more mental leaps and hoops to jump through when comparing the output to the source code. Just like coffescript which also dropped like a rock.

Answer (score 0):

There have been projects for past versions of Bootstrap to convert them to SASS syntax, (such as https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass for Bootstrap 3) but I'm unaware of any such projects for Bootstrap 4.

Now I also use SASS over SCSS in my own projects, but what you need to remember is that it doesn't matter whether a library like Bootstrap uses SCSS or SASS. You can still write your own files in SASS syntax and import variables from SCSS files. That's the whole point of SASS/SCSS in general. Just write *your* files in SASS, and it doesn't matter whether or not Bootstrap is using SCSS.